# UltraGrid as UltraToolBar

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

What I need is a very custom situation.
I need to add UltraGrid to ultraToolbar as normal tool like buttontool. 
Where I need to show customized tabular data.
I have tried to derive a userControl from ToolBase but somehow it didn't work.

I am attaching my code here. It has some errors.
**FilterGrid.cs** UserControl

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid;
    using System.Security.Permissions;
    using Infragistics.Shared.Serialization;
    using Infragistics.Win.AppStyling;

    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
        public partial class FilterGrid : UserControl
        {
            public FilterGrid()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            [TypeConverter(typeof(FilterGrid.GridInternal))]
            [Serializable()]
            private class GridInternal : ToolBase
            {

                internal UltraGrid uGrid = new UltraGrid();
                #region Constructors

                public GridInternal(String key)
                    : base(key)
                {
                    this.SharedProps.Width = 200;
                    this.SharedProps.ToolTipText = "FilterGrid";
                    this.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.DefaultForToolType;
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// Constructor used for de-serialization
                /// </summary>
                protected GridInternal(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context): base(info, context)
                {

                }

                #endregion

                #region Constants

                internal static readonly string DEFAULTVALUE_CUSTOMPROP = "CustomValue";

                #endregion Constants


                #region Base Class Overrides

                #region GetObjectData

                /// <summary>
                /// Called from our base class when ISerializable.GetObjectData is called.  Serialize all custom property data here.
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="info"></param>
                /// <param name="context"></param>
                [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
                protected override void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
                {
                    // Call the base implementation
                    base.GetObjectData(info, context);


                    // Serialize our CustomProp property if necessary.
                    //if (this.ShouldSerializeCustomProp())
                    //    Utils.SerializeProperty(info, "CustomProp", this.CustomProp);
                }



                #endregion GetObjectData



                //#region ISerializable Members

                //public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
                //{
                //    // Call the base implementation
                //    base.GetObjectData(info, context);


                //    // Serialize our CustomProp property if necessary.
                //    if (this.ShouldSerializeCustomProp())
                //        Utils.SerializeProperty(info, "CustomProp", this.CustomProp);
                //}

                //#endregion


                #region Initialize

                /// <summary>
                /// Internal inherited method for initializing the tool when de-serialization completes.
                /// Automatically called by toolbars manager.
                /// </summary>
                protected override void Initialize(ToolsCollectionBase parentCollection)
                {
                    // Let the base do its processing.
                    base.Initialize(parentCollection);


                    // Use the temporary member variable to set the actual ExtraSharedProps properties.
                    // We need to wait until after deserialization is totally complete to ensure that
                    // our ExtraSharedProps object is properly setup.
                    //if (this.serializedProps != null)
                    //{
                    //    this.ExtraSharedProps.customProp = this.serializedProps.customProp;

                    //    this.serializedProps = null;
                    //}

                }

                #endregion Initialize

                #region Clone
                /// <summary>
                /// Returns a cloned copy of the tool.
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="cloneNewInstance">If true, returns a clone of the tool that can serve as an instance of the tool, sharing the same SharedProps object.  If false, returns a tool that can be used as a new tool, with a clone of the original SharedProps object.</param>
                /// <returns></returns>
                protected override Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ToolBase Clone(bool cloneNewInstance)
                {
                    GridInternal tool = new GridInternal(this.Key);
                    tool.InitializeFrom(this, cloneNewInstance);
                    return tool;
                }
                #endregion //Clone

                #endregion Base Class Overrides

                #region CustomProp

                /// <summary>
                /// This is a custom property in a custom tool.
                /// </summary>
                //public string CustomProp
                //{
                //    // Delegate the get/sets for the property to our ExtraSharedProps object

                //    get { return this.ExtraSharedProps.CustomProp; }
                //    set { this.ExtraSharedProps.CustomProp = value; }
                //}

                /// <summary>
                /// Returns a Boolean value that determines whether the CustomProp property is set to its default value.
                /// Checked during serialization to determine if the property should be serialized.
                /// </summary>
                internal protected virtual bool ShouldSerializeCustomProp()
                {
                    // We only want to serialize the property if this tool is the Root tool and the 
                    // property is not set to its default value.
                    return (this.IsRootTool);
                }

                #endregion CustomProp

                protected override Type GetToolbarUIElementType()
                {
                    return typeof(UltraGrid);
                }

                           AccessibleRole rl = AccessibleRole.Pane;
                UIRole roleOnMenus ;
                UIRole roleOnRibbonGroups ;
                UIRole roleOnToolbars;

                protected override AccessibleRole DefaultAccessibleRole
                {
                    get { return this.rl; }
                }

                protected override string DefaultAction
                {
                    get { return "Get"; }
                }

                public override Infragistics.Win.AppStyling.UIRole UIRoleOnMenus
                {
                    get { return this.roleOnMenus; }
                }

                public override Infragistics.Win.AppStyling.UIRole UIRoleOnRibbonGroups
                {
                    get { return this.roleOnRibbonGroups; }
                }

                public override Infragistics.Win.AppStyling.UIRole UIRoleOnToolbars
                {
                    get {return this.roleOnToolbars; }
                }
            }

            private void DrawFilter(UltraToolbarsManager tbm)
            {
                GridInternal gdInternal = new GridInternal("gridInternal");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MyRow"});
                gdInternal.uGrid.DataSource = dt;
                gdInternal.SharedProps.Caption = "FilterGrid";

                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.StateButtonTool stb = new StateButtonTool("isEnabled");
                stb.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
                stb.SharedProps.CustomizerCaption = "Enable";
                stb.SharedProps.Caption = "Enable";

                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.LabelTool lb = new LabelTool("FilterStatus");
                lb.SharedProps.Caption = "FilterStatus";

                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.StateButtonTool filterstb = new StateButtonTool("Applied");
                filterstb.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.ImageOnlyOnToolbars;
                filterstb.SharedProps.CustomizerCaption = "Applied";
                filterstb.SharedProps.Caption = "Applied";

                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.LabelTool lb1 = new LabelTool("SetFilterType");
                lb1.SharedProps.Caption = "SetFilterType";

                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ComboBoxTool cbTool = new ComboBoxTool("FilterList");
                cbTool.SharedProps.Caption = "FilterType";
                cbTool.DropDownStyle = Infragistics.Win.DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
                Infragistics.Win.ValueList vl = new Infragistics.Win.ValueList();

                cbTool.ValueList.ValueListItems.Add("Select");
                cbTool.ValueList.ValueListItems.Add("List1");
                cbTool.ValueList.ValueListItems.Add("List2");
                cbTool.ValueList.ValueListItems.Add("List3");
                cbTool.ValueList.ValueListItems.Add("List4");
                cbTool.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Infragistics.Win.UltraWinToolbars.ButtonTool btReset = new ButtonTool("Reset");
                btReset.SharedProps.DisplayStyle = ToolDisplayStyle.ImageAndText;
                btReset.SharedProps.Caption = "ResetFilters";


                tbm.Tools.AddRange(new ToolBase[] { stb, lb, filterstb, lb1, cbTool, btReset, gdInternal });

                UltraToolbar tb = new UltraToolbar("Filter");
                tbm.Toolbars.AddToolbar("Filter").Tools.AddToolRange(new String[] { "isEnabled", "FilterStatus", "Applied", "SetFilterType", "FilterList", "Reset", "gridInternal" });
               // tb.Tools.AddTool("isEnabled");



            }

            public FilterGrid(UltraToolbarsManager tbm):this()
            {
                DrawFilter(tbm);
            }



        }
    }
```

**Main.cs** main form

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Main : Form
        {
            public Main()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                FilterGrid fg = new FilterGrid(ultraToolbarsManager1);
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
I want to derive a control from Toolbase and show it on UltraToolbar, if it is possible.

Comment: You're going to need to ask a more concise question to receive a useful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I got how to do that.
I created an instance of controlContainerTool and assign my ultragrid to it.
controlContainerTool is added to UltraToolbarsManager and toolbar instance too.

Appearance can be set at design time from code.

One most important thing is to handle scrollbar in the grid if gets larger than expected.